# how do I recover an old python environment?

Tags: python, virtualenv, venv

I am in a bit of a problem, as a server was upgraded, and some old python environments are no longer working. I cannot just activate the environment, but I would like to create a new environment which is a replica of the old environment to the extent possible.

This means installing on the new environment the same version of packages from the old environment.

Is there a way to extract this information from the old environment, for example, into a requirements.txt file? There doesn't seem to be anywhere a requirements.txt file in the old environment I can use.

EDIT: Thank you for the discussion. Yes, it was my mistake for not doing pip freeze before the upgrade, but I wasn't aware things are that flimsy.

Some of the code is old (and I know I will get comments about python 2.7 being used in some of the cases), but for example, when I run pip freeze from one of the activated packages I get:

```
# pip freeze

/.../venv/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I know python 2.7 is installed on the machine, but I looked through all files in the whole server for this object file, and couldn't find it.

Comment: You should just be able to run `venv/bin/pip freeze` to generate the list of installed package, but it's not clear if whatever prevents you from using the environment will cause `pip` to not work, either.

Comment: it is *your* responsibility to maintain your dependencies explicitly. Barring that, the best thing you can do is something like a `pip freeze` or something from within the environment

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the virtual environment has been corrupted and can’t be activated.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon then you can try to use the `pip` that corresponded to that environment. In any case, what I'm stating still stands

Comment: Worst case you can explore the folder structure of the virtual environment and see what version of python and site-packages are installed, etc.

Comment: btw, this is a good reason to use frameworks like `poetry` for handling python projects - it forces you to explicitly specify your requirements, and it generates lockfiles for reconstituting an environment.

Comment: We can't really give more specifics for an answer without knowing, e.g., the type of python distro, general file listing of the env (e.g., you could have a conda env vs. std python env).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shell script which roughly approximates the functionality of `pip freeze`. I have tested it on an environment where I knew the answer (the [Charcoal SmokeDetector project](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector)) and the results are *approximately* right; but there are many Python packages whose package names do not precisely align with the file names.

```
#!/bin/sh

: ${1?"Syntax: $0 <sdenv>">}

site_packages=""
for d in "$1"/lib/python3.?/site-packages "$1"/lib/python3.??/site-packages; do
    test -d "$d" || continue
    [ "$site_packages" ] && echo "$0: ignoring $site_packages" >&2
    site_packages="$d"
    break
done

: ${site_packages?"No lib/python3.*/site_packages found in $1"}

for package_dir in "$site_packages"/*/; do
    case $package_dir in
        *.dist-info/ | *.egg-info/ | */__pycache__/ ) continue;;
    esac
    found=""
    for metadata in "${package_dir%/}"-*.dist-info/METADATA \
                    "${package_dir%/}"-*.egg-info/PKG-INFO; do
        test -f "$metadata" || continue
        awk '/^Name:[ \t]*/ { name=$0; sub(/^Name:[ \t]*/, "", name) }
            /^Version:[ \t]*/ {ver=$0; sub(/^Version:[ \t]*/, "", ver) }
            name && ver { print name "==" ver; found=1; exit }
            END { exit(1-found) }' "$metadata" && found=yes && break
    done
    test "$found" && continue
    package_name=$(basename "$package_dir")
    if [ -f "${package_dir}__init__.py" ]; then
        if [ "${package_name}" != "${package_name#_}" ] &&
               [ -d "$site_packages/${package_name#_}" ]; then
            continue
        fi
        PYTHONPATH="${site_packages%/site-packages}${PYTHONPATH+:}${PYTHONPATH}" \
            python3 <<________HERE 2>/dev/null && found="yes"
import $package_name
ver = $package_name.__version__
print(f'$package_name=={ver}')
________HERE
    fi
    test "$found" && continue
    echo "$0: could not extract metadata for $package_name" >&2
    echo "$package_name"
done
```

In addition to that, this has the usual problems of `pip freeze`; it will list all installed packages, not just the ones you explicitly requested. So if for example you wanted to install the package `se7en` and it has a dependency on `six`, then `six` will also be included in the output, even if it will obviously be unnecessary if a future version of `se7en` drops the dependency on `six`.

For the Smokey dependencies, the above script displays warnings for `dns` (the actual package name is `dnspython`), `attr` (I *think* the actual package name is `attrs` but it weirdly creates a directory with the singular form), `msgpack` (the actual package name is `msgpack-python`), and `pkg_resources` (does not expose a version number).  It could arguably be changed to fix a few of these one way or another, but there are then probably other corner cases which are left uncovered. Consider this a rough sketch anyway.

Comment: This specifically targets Python 3, and assumes your Python is installed as `python3`. It will obviously not work at all on Windows; but then if you are on Windows, you should be very used to things not working.